# Destroy wrapped instance in var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrapped a plugin instance in a variable and I am trying to destroy the created instance. I tried the following code to destroy it but it did not work and gave error of `test1.remove is not a function`.

Kindly let me know how can I destroy it:

```
var test = (function() {
    $( "#" + id ).eip( "save.php", { 
        form_type: "textarea"
    });
});

test1 = new test();
test1.remove();
```

Also folowing didn't execute with `test1 = new test();`:

```
$( "#" + id ).eip( "save.php", { 
    form_type: "textarea"
});
```

Complete Code:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".editq", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('editit'); 



    var test = function() {
    return $( "#" + id ).eip( "save.php", { 
        form_type: "textarea"
    } );
    };

    test1 = test();
    //test1.remove();

    $("span.jeip-editor").remove();
    $( "#" + id  ).click();

    return false;
    });
```

Comment: Use `return` in the `test` function, and don't use `new` to invoke it. It's not a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several notes:

1. You've said *"I have wrapped a plugin instance in a variable and I am trying to destroy the created instance"* but your code is looking up an existing element, calling a plugin on it, and then *removing* the element. Normally if a plugin has the "create/destroy" way of being used, it implements a plugin "method" called "destroy" and you'd use that rather than removing the element. (But this varies by plugin.) E.g.:

   ```
   // Destroy the eip plugin stuff attached to the element
   someElement.eip("destroy"); // Assumes `eip` works this way, as many but not all do
   ```

   But if you need to actually remove the element, `.remove()` is the correct way to do it.
2. `new test()` tries to call the `test` function as a *constructor* function, but it doesn't look like it's designed to be one (except for not having a `return`).

   Just use a normal function, add the necessary `return`, and call it without `new`:

   ```
   var test = function() {
       return $( "#" + id ).eip( "save.php", { 
           form_type: "textarea"
       } );
   };

   test1 = test();
   test1.remove();
   ```

   Note that the above assumes that the `eip` plugin returns the jQuery object for chaining, like most (but not all) jQuery functions and plugins do. If it doesn't:

   ```
   var test = function() {
       var element = $( "#" + id );
       element.eip( "save.php", { 
           form_type: "textarea"
       } );
       return element;
   };
   ```
3. I don't know where the `id` comes from in your code, but I assume you have one somewhere, or you'd be getting a `ReferenceError` when trying to use it. FWIW, I would make that an argument to the function, but I don't know the overall context for this code...
4. I'm also assuming you've declared the `test1` variable somewhere. If you haven't, then in strict mode you'll get a `ReferenceError` and in loose mode you'll fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

---

Side note: I normally prefer function *declarations* to function expressions (although function expressions are frequently quite useful). So if it were me, I'd probably do:

```
function test() {
    // ...stuff here...
}
```

rather than

```
var test = function() {
    // ...stuff here...
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the wrapping instance code is working but I am getting same old error on `test1.remove();` i.e `test1 is undefined`

Comment: What I am actually doing is creating inline edit on click of a button the code runs fine but when I save it. It make double instances on inline editing ad so on. So I thought by detroying that instance it may do the trick I have updated my question with comlete js code I am using to perform the functionality I am seeking to do.

Comment: @user3027531: *"Thanks, the wrapping instance code is working but I am getting same old error on test1.remove(); i.e test1 is undefined"* Did you add the `return`? (And did you try both versions of that? See the warning I mentioned about some plugins not returning the instance for chaining.) Because if so, you shouldn't be getting that: http://jsbin.com/fepinume/1

Comment: Just FYI I am using this plugin `https://josephscott.org/code/javascript/jquery-edit-in-place/`

Comment: As far as my question concerns its answered quite awesomely an many thanks for taking you time for that as the second piece of your code is working fine it is destroying but in that case the editor is not appearing as it got destroyed. Any idea how can I stop my above (updated) function to create multiple instances. So I'll see `one inline editor` in all possible scenarios?

Comment: @user3027531: If you mean, you want to avoid calling `eip` on the element if you've previously called `eip` on the element, I'd probably just set a flag: `var elm = $("#" + id); if (!elm.data("eip-initialized")) { elm.data("eip-initialized", true).eip({...}); }` (or the `eip` plugin might have a way for you to ask it if it's been set up on an element). (Note that that code would be more complicated if there were any chance of multiple elements matching the selector; but as it's an `id` selector, we know it'll be zero or one.)

Comment: Thanks alot, My issue is 100% solved now. Thank you for a very detailed asnwer I learned multile things today :-D